# Finding a tail-probability with the momentgenerating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

I wonder if it is possible to estimate $\mathbb{P}(X<t)$ with the moment generating function?

This question popped up when I tried to proof this estimate $\mathbb{P}(T_a<t)\leq e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}$, since I know that $\mathbb{E}(e^{-uT_a})=e^{-a\sqrt{2u}}$, with $T_a$ being the hitting time of $a$ of a brownian motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\lambda>0$ we have

$$\mathbb{P}(X<t) = \mathbb{P}(e^{\lambda \cdot X}<e^{\lambda \cdot t}) \leq \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{e^{\lambda \cdot t}}{e^{\lambda \cdot X}} \right) = e^{\lambda \cdot t} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda \cdot X}$$

Applying this to the hitting time $X=T_a$ yields

$$\mathbb{P}(T_a<t) \leq e^{\lambda \cdot t} \cdot e^{-a \cdot \sqrt{2\lambda}}$$

as $\mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda T_a}) = e^{-a \sqrt{2\lambda}}$. Choose a suitable $\lambda$ to obtain the estimate

$$\mathbb{P}(T_a<t) \leq \exp \left( - \frac{a^2}{2t} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I really liked the tricks used in the first line!